# Retrieve Windows USB device power status from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, usb

I am aware from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/comparing-usb-device-states-to-wdm-device-states that:

> Device power states in the WDM model can be summarized as follows:
>
> - D0 - The working state. The device is fully powered.
> - D1/D2 - The intermediate sleep states. These states allow the device to be armed for remote wakeup.
> - D3 - The deepest sleep state. Devices in state D3 cannot be armed for remote wakeup.

So, for a device, I can seemingly see this state in Windows (10) Device Manager/ [right-click device node/Properties]/ Details/ Property: Power data/ Value: Current power state - and in the example below, the power state of my chosen device is apparently D0:

[image: device manager]

However, if I use USBView ([Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview)), then - for the same example device - I get:

[image: USBview]

... that its current power state is D2 (that is, PowerDeviceD2).

So, now I don't really know which source to trust, as the information supplied is contradictory.

But in any case - is there a way (a compiled program, maybe a Powershell script, even some C/C++ code that I should compile myself, with or without administrative privileges) - that would allow me to obtain the correct power state a particular USB device to be in, at the current time (from the perspective of Windows), from the command line?

(I would love if this kind of a utility just dumped all of the USB devices connected to the PC, along with their power states, to the terminal as a list; however, I would be more than pleased if I also have to enter USB VID:PID for an individual USB device manually)

Answer (score 1):

pnputil /enum-devices /instanceid "<device instance path>" /properties

This will list out many of the device properties associated with a device. On at least some versions of Windows, the DEVPKEY_Device_PowerData is the CM_POWER_DATA structure which includes the current DEVICE_POWER_STATE.

Comment: The /properties appears to be supported in later versions of Windows 11.